# In useState is rendering but when i push to the same useState it doesnt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im doing a onclick that changes the individual numbers colors, its working fine in useState(the colors change):
const [totalNumbers, setTotalNumbers]: any = useState([1, 2, 3]);

But when i push to useState: totalNumbers.push(event.target.id), only the array is increased but the colors didnt render

```
        const newBet: React.FC = () => {
    
  const [range, setRange] = useState(gamesJson[whichLoteriaIsVar].range);
  const numbersList = Array.from(Array(25).keys()).map((num) => num + 1);
    
      const [totalNumbers, setTotalNumbers]: any = useState([]);
      const changeButtonColor = (event: any) => {
        totalNumbers.push(Number(event.target.id));
        console.log(totalNumbers);
        setTotalNumbers(totalNumbers);
      };
    
     return(
            <NumbersContainer>
              {numbersList.map((num) => (
                <Numbers
                  onClick={changeButtonColor}
                  id={num.toString()}
                  className={
                    totalNumbers.indexOf(num) === -1 ? 'desactive' : 'active'
                  }
                  key={num}
                >
                  {formatNumber(num)}
                </Numbers>
              ))}
            </NumbersContainer>
        )
        }
```

Comment: `numbersList = 25` ... how does a number have a map method? `numbersList.map`

Comment: Why have both `totalNumbers` and `selectedNumbers`? Why not just update selectedNumbers?

Comment: epascarello, that just for explain, not the original numbersList

Comment: Alexander, i did that and the problem is solved but isnt rendering the colors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const changeButtonColor = (event: any) => {
   const newtotalNumbers = totalNumbers.slice()
   newtotalNumbers.push(Number(event.target.id));
   setSelectedNumbers(newtotalNumbers );
};
```

Comment: It didnt work, i made some changes(now the array is ok, but isnt rendering the color)

Answer (score 0):

```
  const changeButtonColor = (event: any) => {
    totalNumbers.push(Number(event.target.id));
    console.log(totalNumbers);
    setTotalNumbers([...totalNumbers]);
  };
```

Solved my problem